# Extracting General Ledger report data via Quickbooks Online V3 API

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I am to build an application using data from the QuickBooks Online API. The requirement is to get the "General Ledger" report data. I could not find an API endpoint sharing data for this report. Please point me to correct API endpoint for this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/companyId/reports/BalanceSheet?name=value[&...]
```

All of the API reports can be found here at: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/reports

Comment: So, you mean to say Balance Sheet API Report is the General Ledger report on quickbooks UI?

Comment: General Ledger is not exposed through the API. Only the only available reports are listed at https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/reports

Comment: @WilliamLorfing I'm not sure I understand your comment (or it's possibly out of date?). The page you link to has General Ledger at the bottom. But I'm getting a "Permission Denied" error when I try it, would you know anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this too. I pulled the following transaction reports and glued them together:

- Purchase Expense Line
- Bill Payment Line
- Bill Expense Line
- Journal Entry
- Deposits

You might need other reports as well - eg, revenue, cash receipts. And also standard data tables such as chart of accounts, customer/vendor lists, etc.

I was able to get my reconstructed GL to tie to the front-end GL report that you can pull from QBO.

Good luck!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).